# How can I configure Google DFP to display only "text" ads (no images) in case of adsense fallback?

Tags: configuration, adsense, fallback, google-dfp

I would like to configure the adsense-fallback in google DoubleClick for Publishers, but use Text-ONLY ads (no image ads). Despite the fact, that I set the Ad type to "text"-ONLY as default in the network settings AND the fact that I set the Ad type to "text"-ONLY at each and every ad unit, I still get image and flash ads on my live website (even the preview tool in Google DFP shows text-ONLY ads)

I even set the default settings in my adsense account to text only.
So please anyone: Tell me what to do, so that all adsense fallback ads are text-only in google DFP!